SwaggerUI not authenticating for Web API methods with non-default policy
I'm having a weird problem with authentication in SwaggerUI for my ASP.NET Core Web API.
For APIs with the default authorization policy applied, clicking on the padlock brings up an authorizations popup with details of Entra authentication and my clientId, clicking on the Authorize button takes me to the Microsoft login page and then executing that API (or any of the other APIs that use the default policy), have the token passed through and everything works as expected.
However, for APIs that have a different policy specified (e.g. admin), clicking on the padlock brings up an empty popup with the title "Available Authorizations". Also when I've authorized a different API, all those that use the default policy have a black padlock but those that use a different policy still have greyed padlocks. Executing any of these APIs do not send any auth tokens and thus return 401 responses.
I just need all APIs with an authorize attribute to use the same authorization and let my Web API decide if the logged in user has permission or not.
I don't know why Swagger is differentiating between the policies.
My program.cs code:
const string entra = "Entra";

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();

    c.AddSecurityDefinition(entra, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri($"{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"]?.Split(' ').ToDictionary(x => x, x => x)
            }
        }
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = entra }
            },
            ["OpenID"]
        }
    });
});

// Other stuff

var app = builder.Builder()

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]);
    c.OAuthUsePkce();
    c.OAuthScopes(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"]);
    c.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});

/Diagnostics is default policy, /Diagnostics/Full requires admin policy

Clicking the padlock on /Diagnostics shows (TenantId blanked out)

Padlock on /Diagnostics/Full shows:

